# How do you apply utilitarian concepts to answer this?

Tags: utilitarianism

You are the prime minister of a state being threatened by an insurgent group of 1000 men. You received the news that the insurgents are hiding in the hills with a community of innocent civilians of about 500. You have the option of pushing a button that will launch a missile attack to the area where insurgents are hiding. Doing so will kill the civilians but will solve your state’s insurgent issue. Would you push the button?

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thinly disguised Trolley Problem is thinly disguised. Only now it's 1000 bad guys alive on one track and 500 good guys dead with 1000 bad guys on the other track.

Answer (score 0):

Though not bad I don't believe that this question suits to this site.

I believe you are looking forward to getting an answer based on philosophical application.  So let us assume that this PM is a philosopher.

A philosopher always tries to analyze all the possible situations (even the ones that most people neglect) to resolve a crisis.  He never likes to sacrifice innocent people's life in any way.

Sometimes the aim of some revolts may be good. So a PM should do self assessment first because this type of a situation could be tackled only after analyzing all the situations. Though 'to press the button' is there a last resort, in my opinion, he would get help from his assistants/somewhere to solve such an issue in another way.

"Let a hundred guilty be acquitted, but one innocent should not be convicted."  You could apply this philosophical concept here partially.

The Mahabharata, one of the epics, has multiple mentions of the phrase *'Ahimsa Paramo Dharma'* (अहिंसा परमॊ धर्मः), which literally means: non-violence is the highest moral virtue.

> Ahimsa is the highest virtue, Ahimsa is the highest self-control,
>   Ahimsa is the greatest gift, Ahimsa is the best suffering, Ahimsa is
>   the highest sacrifice, Ahimsa is the finest strength, Ahimsa is the
>   greatest friend, Ahimsa is the greatest happiness, Ahimsa is the
>   highest truth, and Ahimsa is the greatest teaching.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahi%E1%B9%83s%C4%81

In order to complete this please read this one also:  https://www.hinduhistory.info/dharma-himsa-tathaiva-cha-swami-chinmayananda/

If you could combine these two ideas, 'to press the button' seldom comes only as a last resort. That was why I said that the cause of a righteous violence should also be treated justly by self assessment.

And he would get confidence from this concept: [Dharmo Rakshati Rakshitah](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26513/what-is-the-true-meaning-of-the-shlok-dharmo-rakshati-rakshitah)

If you could apply one or more philosophies according to the situation, you would be able to tackle a crisis wisely.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to calculate the utility of

-the governement being threatened (does the governemnt promote happiness better than the alternative)

-the utility of the lives of the insurgents

-the utility of the lives of the collateral kill

-the utility of the impact on the public image of pushing the button (diplomatic relations, war crime, fear, more revolts etc....)

That's an awful lot of consequences to compute, and I'm sure I'm forgetting a lot of potential issues on either side of the choice.